# PayPal PaymentsException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

i'm going to sale a subscribe to my service's users and i've trying to setup paypal in my asp.net webform website with c# but i'm getting an error that is unknown for me. I wonder if that code i'm wrote is ok or not.

code:

```
var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
string payerId = userId.ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
{
    var itemList = new ItemList()
    {
        items = new List<Item>() 
        {
           new Item()
           {
                name = "Weekly Subscribe",
                currency = "USD",
                price = "15",
                quantity = "1",
                sku = "sku"
           }
        }
    };

    var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };
    var baseURI = "http://localhost:1067/Pages/General/BackFromPayPal.aspx?";
    var guid = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000));
    var redirectUrl = baseURI + "id=" + item.PaidHistoryID;
    var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
    {
        cancel_url = redirectUrl + "&isPaid=false",
        return_url = redirectUrl + "&isPaid=true"
    };

    var details = new Details()
    {
        tax = "0",
        shipping = "0",
        subtotal = "15"
    };


    var amount = new Amount()
    {
        currency = "USD",
        total = "15.00", // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
        details = details
    };

    var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
    transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
    {
         description = "description",
         invoice_number = Common.GetRandomInvoiceNumber(),
         amount = amount,
         item_list = itemList
    });

    var payment = new Payment()
    {
        intent = "sale",
        payer = payer,
        transactions = transactionList,
        redirect_urls = redirUrls
    };

    try
    {
        var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
        var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();
        while (links.MoveNext())
        {
            var link = links.Current;
            if (link.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
            {
                        //this.flow.RecordRedirectUrl("Redirect to PayPal to approve the payment...", link.href);
            }
        }

    Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id); 
    var paymentId = createdPayment.id;
    var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId, transactions = createdPayment.transactions };

    var executedPayment = createdPayment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);

    }
    catch (PayPalException ex)
    {
        if (ex is ConnectionException)
        {
             Label11.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        else
        {
             Label11.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
     }
```

Comment: did you set clientId and clientSecret in your web.config file?

Comment: @ValNolav yes, i've set PayPal SDK settings. i'm working in live mode

Comment: @Morteza did you got any solution for that, I am facing the same issue on
 ```var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);```